# How to create a new user in firebase using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am making a web app. For now i am able to enter and retrieve data in firebase. I want to enter the email and password details of my form to the "Users" tab under "authentication" of firebase and then i am trying to login.

The following is my code to enter my data to user.

```
 function submitForm(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

 //get values
 var name = getInputVal('name');
 var address = getInputVal('address');
 var email = getInputVal('email');
 var phone = getInputVal('phone');
 var password = getInputVal('password');

 enterUser(email, password);
 saveMessage(name, address, email, phone, password);
 //show alert
 document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'block';
 //hide alert after three secs
 setTimeout(function() {
     document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'none';
 }, 3000);
 document.getElementById('contactform').reset();
 }


 function enterUser(name, password) {
 if ((name) && (password)) {
     firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(name, 
 password).then(function(user) {
         // Enters the new user fields
         console.log(user.email);
         // ...
     });
 }
 }
```

The first function "submitform" works when i click a submit button on my DOM. This function stores all the data into a collection "messages" in firebase. After that through my "enterUser" function i am trying to create the user with email and password entered in the "submitForm" and enter it into the "users authentication" of firebase. The problem is, it is not creating any user as shown by the figure below.

[image: User-Authenticaiton]

But the data is being stored in the "messages" collection in firebase.(shown below)[image]

My question: How to save the email and password in the "users-authentication"?

Comment: is enterUser being called? (You can know from the console.log)

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes, you can see it in the code, inside submitForm function it is indeed being called. The submitForm has an action event as: document.getElementById('contactform').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

Comment: what firebase version are you using?

Comment: You should check if the create user function gives back any errors ([Link to docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword)). But my first guess is its going wrong because you are trying to create a user with his/her name instead of the email. The function is called _createUserWithEmailAndPassword_ and not _createUserWithNameAndPassword_

Comment: Actually, i was able to do the correction...the first thing was as stated by @AndréKool i had named it wrong. The second was if one is trying to sign in through firebase with the help of email address, one has to provide a password that is atleast 6 characters long. Well it worked for me. But a new problem has arisen. The page to which i want it to direct after login is not opening. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have sign-in method enabled

[image]

Comment: Yes, i have enabled it. I actually had enabled it much before.